# What should I provide in the config.cmake of my library

Tags: cmake

I have a library that I have developed and this library has some dependencies on other libraries. To be able to use this library in other projects, I need to provide a config.cmake. My question is, what do I need to put in my config.camke. Normally this config.cmake files have an INCLUDE_DIRS, LIBRARIES and EXECUTABLE variables as well as FOUND (and each one is properly set with the library, executables, and paths). However, I see that if I only give this when I try to compile the project depending on my library I get linking errors saying that the executable is missing the library that my library depends on. Is there a way that I can avoid this by doing a better config.cmake?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Because there are so many examples of how to do this out there (including [the official manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html)) that we would need your specific code and error to help you. Just guessing: If you deliver the "depending library" as a binary, then you must link depend on it using CMake's "imported library" feature and a `target_link_libraries()` dependency.